# Java reflection API and invoking a method with variable number of arguments

Tags: java, reflection, methods, parameter-passing, invoke

I have a problem trying to solve a situation, when I use Java Reflection API to invoke a method that accepts a variable number of parameters. Every time I try to do that I get an "NoSuchMethodException".

My declaration of method to invoke:

```
public void AddShow(String movieName, String cinemaName, String... days) {
}
```

And the code for the method that does the invocation:

```
public void Exec(String command){
    try {
        String[] words = command.split(" ");
        String commandName = words[0];
        Class<? extends UserInterface> thisClass = (Class<? extends UserInterface>)getClass();
        Class<String>[] par = new Class[words.length-1];
        String[] params = new String[words.length-1];
        for(int i = 1; i< words.length; i++){
            params[i-1] = words[i];
            try {
                par[i-1] = (Class<String>) Class.forName("java.lang.String");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("If this shows up, something is siriously wrong... Waht have you done?!");
            }
        }
        Method method;
        if(par.length != 0) {
            method = thisClass.getMethod(commandName, par);
            method.invoke(new UserInterface(CinemaDb), (Object[])params);
        } else {
            method = thisClass.getMethod(commandName);
            method.invoke(new UserInterface(CinemaDb));
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        System.out.println("Security error, sry again.");
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong command, try again (check the parameters)!");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.out.println("You don't have access rights, try again.");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong arguments, try again.");
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        System.out.println("Invocation error, try again.");
    }
}
```

If you know how can I change my Exec method to solve this problem, I will be really grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Your Exec method should be named exec, and instead of doing Clas.forName("java.lang.string"), you may just do String.class : much shorter and safer.

Comment: Why should it me named "exec"? Because of the naming conventions or are you refering to anything else.

 And thanks for the tip, it made my code clearer.

Comment: Yes, to respect the Java naming conventions. Methods always start with a lower-case letter in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The varargs part is represented as `String[]` after compilation, so use `String[].class`

In your case it will be a bit harder, since you can't know exactly how many of the arguments there are before the varargs. So if you invoke `showFoo str1 str2 str3 str4` you can't know how many string arguments there are before the varargs.

So you can put a delimiter in your command string, which will tell the parser where to add the `String[].class`. Another option is to simply call `getMethods()` and get the required method only by its name (iterate and compare the names). But you won't be able to use overloading.

That said, I don't think it is a really good idea to have such a specially-formatted string for reflective executions (unless it comes from an external system, but then it might be a security issue)

Comment: Yeah but I am using the same Exec method to run a couple more methods, so I am not able to find out is the incomming paramaters are part of Array or are they normal parameters

Comment: well, you can't because that's the scenario. Check my updated 3rd paragraph for an alternative, but generally, that's what it is.

Comment: Well you might be right, but I am creating a user interface, that accepts commands passed by user, so insted of creating one big switch to use every command I thought it might be easier and simpler to use the reflection API...

Comment: does the user input the commands as strings, containing method names? Can't he press buttons, for example

Comment: It is a command line tool, so not really. I tried to keep it as simple as possible, but I don't think there is a way to do it without adding additional character as delimiter in the command.

Answer (score 4):

varargs in Java are implemented via arrays, so the parameters are `String.class, String.class, and String[].class`.

Comment: Hmmm, is there any other way? Because I am not able to find out if the incomming String parameters are part of the Array or if they are just normal parameters...

Answer (score 3):

The `Object[]` holding the params should have two `String` params and `String[]`, you're passing a flat `String[]`.

Comment: Yeah but I am using the same Exec method to run a couple more methods, so I am not able to find out is the incomming paramaters are part of Array or are they normal parameters

Comment: @Tromax Nonetheless, that's the issue. You'll need to figure out a way to figure out what you need for the reflective call.